# Absolute lost at words for how to describe this softbody/fluid?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, soft-body

I recently saw a video [THE VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3t3pIfcw5DA)

It's of a softbody(i think) cow getting mashed up and broke apart, I have no idea how to describe it so i cant search for a tutorial and the closest thing i found was this
[THE OTHER VIDER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMLx5l58gQg&t=34s)

How would i do this

Answer (score 3):

This is a soft body plastic deformation and tearing simulation. Currently, Blender's built-in soft body system does not support tearing, and (to my knowledge) the Mantaflow fluid system is not appropriate for the extremely high viscosities needed to emulate it.

Thankfully, there are a couple of free options you can use:

#### Molecular Addon

Probably your best bet, the [Molecular addon](https://blenderartists.org/t/moleculars-physics/521682) uses a very flexible meshless mass-spring system to approximate a wide range of soft body physics (when combined with [CubeSurfer](https://github.com/Pyroevil/CubeSurfer)) as well as simulate granular flow. Most relevant to your problem is the feature for breaking bonds. Unfortunately the documentation is offline, so I cannot link it to you now.

#### FLIP Fluids

FLIP Fluids is a fluid solver for blender that supports high-viscosity liquids. While it appears to be a paid addon, it is possible to use it if you compile from source. For your problem, all you need to do is crank the fluid viscosity up and have a blob of fluid in the initial shape of your body.

In the future, I hope [the new soft body sim](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/User:Mattoverby/GSoC2020/mattoverby_proposal) and [particle nodes](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/2020-07-28-particle-nodes-status/14588) will be up to the task.